# Can users ask to have comments removed?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-replies

Recently, while browsing stackoverflow, I came upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186949/does-python-have-any-direct-appoach-to-compare-two-txt-files). As precedent dictates, we usually ask to see what the asker has tried.  In response, the asker asked me to remove the comment. Should users ask to have comments removed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They can ask, but I'd just ignore that request.

If the OP has a problem with a comment he or she can flag your comment for mod attention. In this specific case, the mod would decline the flag though, there is nothing wrong with your request for more details.

You can do the same with that comment; I can understand it if someone were to flag it as non-constructive, for example. Either a moderator can then remove the comment, or, if enough people flag it too, it'll be auto-deleted.

Comment: More than that, I would mark the OP comment as off topic/not constructive and with enough such flags (5 I think) his comment will be auto deleted.